# How to get data from two tables using SQLALCHEMY

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Let say I have a model

```
import os    
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy    
db = SQLAlchemy()    
class Students(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "students"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)


class Hobbies(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "hobbies"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String)
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("students.id"), nullable=False)
```

Now in flask I have following code

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import *
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://junaid:junaid@localhost:5432/UOB"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)
```

Now I get all the record in the table Hobbies

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

with app.app_context():
    a = Hobbies.query.all()
```

I want to get the result like

Hobby.ID, Hobby.title, Hobby.description, Student.name  (The filter is Hobby.student_id = Students.id)

I want to print all the record in the hobbies table with student name in short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Sharing if someone else can benefit from this.

```
hobbies_with_stud = db.session.query(Students, Hobbies).join(Hobbies, Hobbies.student_id == Students.id).all()

for record in hobbies_with_stud:
    print(record.Hobbies.title + " is the hobby of "+ record.Students.name)
```